# How to pass dynamic value into FilenameFilter?

Tags: java, file-io

Here are what my files look like in a directory

- Brake_20130901.xml
- Tire_20130902.xml
- Wheel_20130903.xml
- Brake_20130910.xml
- Brake_20131001.zip

Depends on what type of car part (Brake, Wheel, Tire), I only want to return those xml files.  Eg. If I receive Brake, then I want only 2 files **AND** I only want to return xml files. So in the above example, I only want to get back

- Brake_20130901.xml
- Brake_20130910.xml.

Here's my code

```
String carPart = "Brake";  //This value is dynamic so I can't hard code it

FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {

public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
return (name.contains(carPart) && name.endsWith(".xml"));}
};
```

I got the error that it can't find carPart variable.  I tried to use this.carPart but no luck also.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variable final
`final String carPart = "Brake";`

If you look closely at error it might be saying

> Cannot refer to a non-final variable carPart inside an inner class defined in a different method

so doing above should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I created a class that implement the FilenameFilter interface and it seems to work now.

Comment: Declaring as final means it cannot be dynamic which is the key part to this question